# Journey Builder Goal Criteria Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, filters

I am creating a new version of an existing journey that I have as I noticed an error with the way contacts pass through (see image below):

[image: Population Error]

The fluctuations of populations did not make any sense. I believe that the problem is the goal and its exit criteria. It prompts the following error message:

> At least one attribute in this filter criteria could produce multiple matching values. By default, Journey Builder uses the first matching value. You can use attribute-to-attribute comparison to determine the right match. [Learn More](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5)

The goal has three criteria of:

status equals A OR
status equals B OR
status equals C

with the exit option checked.

I have two questions:

1- What exactly is the error message that I am getting, I read the documentation and I still am a bit confused?

2- How do I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The issue is that the filter uses a one->many relationship. For example purposes, think of an order confirmation journey where the goal is to get the contact to fill out a survey (tracked by an isSurveyCompleted field). Your contact could have gone through the journey multiple times for different order ID’s. Since you’d have to link the order data extension to the contact model on contact key, a row would come back for every order they’ve placed. There would not be a way to guarantee that the ‘isSurveyCompleted’ field is from the correct order. If I filled out the survey for my first order, but not my second, I may still meet the goal the second time I enter the journey.

2) The solution to this is to use attribute to attribute comparison in your goal filter. Your left attribute in my example would be order id (from journey data). This is the unique row in the data extension that was injected into the journey. You would need to map this to order id from the attribute group using contact data. Keeping the example going, the end filter would be:

OrderId (Journey data) = OrderId (Contact data)
AND
isSurveyCompleted (Contact data) = true

This will ensure we are checking the unique row for which a contact entered the journey, and not just the most recent row in the data extension for that contact.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand the issue a little better now. This is a no re-entry journey though, and I am trying to fix this issue how you explained, however the only data available to build a goal criteria is contact data. Is there a reason why I cannot select journey data? The criteria that I am looking for is part of the entry data for this journey.

Comment: Entry object is salesforce contact data btw

Comment: I guess I was wrong in thinking that you could use journey data for goal criteria, but that method would work in a decision split, if you wanted to create a different path for them to exit, as an alternative.